# How do I handle a variable that is mainly 0 in multiple regression analysis in R?

Tags: r, regression

I have tried transforming the variable (x; *shown below*) using various methods but with nothing changing as 0 is so prominent. How would I handle the variable below in multiple regression analysis as it is predominantly zeros and thus very asymmetrically distributed? Can it be transformed? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
x <- c(rep( x = 0, times = 5473 ),7,8,9,9,9.5,10,11.1,11.8,12,13,13,13,17.7,19,27)
```

Comment: Why do you want to transform it?

Comment: In your multiple regression, how many of your variables are zero-inflated? Some? All? Only one?

Comment: I'd be scared about the high leverages of the few positive values and the induced overfitting. No transformation will help to fight this problem effectively without regularization, not even a dummy transformation. Using squared terms will make the problem even more pronounced.

Comment: @Michael Frank Harrell's suggestion removes that problem about high leverage.  The idea is to conduct nearly separate fits at $x=0$ and elsewhere.  Using a dummy variable implies the error variance is estimated from all the residuals, whereas actually doing two separate fits would yield two separate variance estimates. In either case, the pile of zeros creates no leverage.

Comment: You would effectively estimate multiple parameters on information of 20 observations. I am pretty sure that these observations are associated with high leverages. Interesting question anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume x is a predictor, not the dependent variable.  Fit x as quadratic with an exception that allows for a discontinuity at zero, i.e., add an indicator variable for x > 0.

Comment: The approach sounds good and can work.  But given we know nothing about the other variables, I'm curious why you recommend a quadratic.  Note, too--this came up in a recently submitted paper--that the model you recommend is agnostic about the continuity of the response.  It merely allows for a response at $x=0$ that doesn't fit with the functional form for the remaining responses.  Almost equivalently, it can be understood as not predicting anything about responses in the interval $(0, 7).$

Comment: I only recommended quadratic because we don't know if it's linear for x>0 and there's not enough non-zero data points to figure knots in a spline function.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to estimate, sometimes it is useful with imbalanced data to re-sample the data. There are various algorithms out to resample your data. You can undersample your zeros to prevent them from dominating the model. You can oversample (aka duplicate) your non-zero values to make them have a higher impact on your model. You can use another algorithm such as the SMOGN algorithm to generate sample data.

These techniques can be effective when your data is actually imbalanced (such as when the $ spent per person who clicks an advertisement is usually zero). However, you need to be careful that the zeros are meaningful and don't represent missing data before you consider sampling techniques.

Additionally, sampling won't help if you actually have two categories and are trying to force them into a single regression line. The correct answer might be to categorize the zeros and non-zeros first, and then perform a regression on only the non-zeros. For example, if you're looking at how much a person will spend after clicking an advertisement you might have a logistic regression to predict whether or not they will purchase (are they zero or not), and then a regression that ignores zero to determine how much the will spend if they do purchase.

Comment: Note: With only your x-values there is no way to evaluate which algorithms to use or what the problems might be with different methods. All we can do is give general ideas.

Comment: Removing some of your data to make a method work is not good statistical practice and just means that the methods you are using are faulty.  Plus you will automatically make the method fail when applied prospectively because new samples will not be oversampled.  See http://fharrell.com/post/class-damage for more information.

Comment: Not arguing that it has serious drawbacks. But when given the choice between grossly imbalanced classes or overfitting due to dropping data points...sometimes you have to get the model to work.

Comment: No.  Getting the model to work in this context makes making it fail on purpose.  Use a valid method, i.e., one that allows for any possible imbalance, e.g. logistic regression or a probability machine.

Comment: Class imbalance algorithms exist because they work when you have no other options except to quit. If there is another algorithm that will work then use it. But when there is too much imbalance for any algorithm to handle you make trade-offs to get a working model that is significantly better than random chance even if it isn't perfect.

Comment: That is incorrect.  Making the predictive tool quit working prospectively where you don't undersample is no solution, and there are many existing solutions.  See http://fharrell.com/post/classification .  When outcomes are not common it is necessary to model _tendencies_ not make forced-choice decisions.

Comment: This comment thread may reflect a clash of cultures and suppositions more than it does a real difference of opinion: when data are scarce and expensive to obtain, sampling is manifestly a poor idea, as @FrankHarrell claims.  With an enormous dataset, one that likely isn't even a random (or even representative) sample of a process, it may indeed be advantageous to select a suitable subset for analysis, as Adam advocates.  If you wish to resolve this discussion fruitfully, then, consider describing the kinds of applications you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. I think you've described the issue very well. I find that "it depends" on the situation and one size does not fit all. Hence why my original answer is more caveats than answer. There isn't enough information to answer the original question so we can provide tools and a list of considerations before using the tools.

Comment: @whuber that is not at all the case.   When oversampling the minor category results in a method that does not apply to the future use in the field, you are smoked.  This is simply bad statistical practice, and statistics and probability has a lot to do with this problem.  The total number of observations has little to do with this.

Comment: @Frank Although I'm sympathetic with that position, I think you have overstated it for the simple reason that probability has relatively little to tell us about making inferences (or predictions) from non-probability samples. When a procedure that seems at odds with statistical principles demonstrably works, I will seek (admittedly with some scepticism) to understand why and characterize the circumstances under which it can be expected to work, rather than dismiss it out of hand as "bad practice."

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing that.  If you have a cohort of subjects that is not randomly sampled, and you have as measured covariates the variables used to obtain the non-random sample, conditioning on these variables you'll get the right absolute probabilities.

Comment: Sure. You'll get the right probabilities. In the example case I can make a model that is 99.7% correct by always outputting 0. Using a sampling method to handle class imbalance will cause over-fitting and my model accuracy may go down in overall accuracy, but become much more accurate for non-zero values. But if the non-zero values have a higher business relevance than the zero values this is useful even if it provides a statistically higher error.

Comment: The 99.7% will be pertinent and you'll seldom beat that by using any predictors.  So the oversampling is moot anyway.    For business relevance, be consistent with optimum decision making and use a probability model coupled with utility/loss/cost function to make best decisions.